# submit a command to a local Linux FIFO queue

Tags: linux, bash, resources, queue, jobs

As an example, I have a program call ./foo install on my linux server. However, this ./foo program consumes a lot of memory and CPU resources.

Since ./foo program is executed frequency by other servers through ssh connection, I want to control ./foo usage to prevent overloading my server.

I'm looking for a local FIFO queue tool (listener) to handle all ./foo executions.

e.g.

runJob ./foo &
runJob ./foo &
runJob ./foo &

As result, although ./foo are executed parallel, I want to the queue tool (e.g. runJob in this case) to handle job execution in FIFO sequence.

Is there such a tool in Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If FIFO is not a strict requirement, you can easily do it with GNU `parallel`:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    parallel --gnu --semaphore --fg --id myjob -j 1  sleep 15 &
done
```

This starts at most `1` job at a time (counted per username and job `--id`).

With `ps` you'll notice that only one `sleep 15` is executed at a time, while the other `parallel` processes hang out and wait for it.